# Android SDK Google Services Maps API V2 giving error

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I am running the application on my mobile because I can't get emulator to install Google Play Services and therefore I don't have debug. Basically I want to display a map from google maps. I am pretty sure my problem is from my XML since it's the only thing that is not auto-generated.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mytravelbuddy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Travel Buddy"
        android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation"  
         >

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mytravelbuddy.MainActivity"
            android:label="Travel Buddy"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mytravelbuddy.Itinerary"
            android:label="Itinerary">
        </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.myApiKey"
    android:value="myApiKey"/>    
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Here is my XML file of the class:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:minHeight="75dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Itinerary" 
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
          />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there something wrong with this code since I can't debug it.

EDIT:
Here is the logcat i managed to get:

```
12-11 19:56:14.793: W/dalvikvm(1557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a39b90)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): Process: com.example.mytravelbuddy, PID: 1557
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mytravelbuddy/com.example.mytravelbuddy.Itinerary}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.example.mytravelbuddy.Itinerary.onCreate(Itinerary.java:30)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     ... 11 more
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at maps.af.be.a(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at maps.af.bd.a(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at cmi.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
12-11 19:56:14.903: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your KEY" />
```

Not:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.yourKEY"
        android:value="your KEY" />
```

Keep `API_KEY` at end of `android:name`.